# как изменить порядок в прокрутке слайдов slick

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Есть несложный слайдер:

```
$('.slider-wrap-mobile').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 4000,
  infinite: false
});
```

количество слайдов 4. Каким образом я могу изменить порядок слайдов, а именно: 1-й > 3-й > 2-й > 4-й, учитывая autoplay.

Comment: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/

Comment: Не совсем понятно, для чего это?
Если хотите поменять очерёдность показа какого-либо контента - просто расположите этот контент в нужно порядке. На сколько я знаю, из коробки skick не предоставляет такой возможности.

Comment: проблема в том что слайды подтягиваются с админки wordpress-а. Задавать в админке необходимую последовательность тоже не вариант.

Comment: хотите костыль - отсортите слайды на js перед вызовом `$.slick()`